# Same onclick function but different buttons and slightly different result

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently trying to create a shopping cart for my website and was wondering how i differentiate the buttons when clicking.

Here's a picture of my website:
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdeDY.png)

If you look under each item there is a price and plus sign. When I hit the plus sign I want to be able to tell the name of the item. Like when I hit the plus sign by Hawaiian shirt 1, I want to be able to know that it's Hawaiian shirt 1. Each plus sign has the same onclick -> "addToCart()". I will show the code for the first 3 items and hopefully, that will be enough for an example to be created.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class = "island-item"> 
  <img  class = "itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 1</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
   $60
   <img id = "Hawaiian Shirt 1" onclick = "addToCart()" class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "island-item"> 
 <img  class = "itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 2">
 <center>Hawaiian Shirt 2</center>
 <div class="priceAmount">
   $60
   <img id = "Hawaiian Shirt 2" onclick = "addToCart()" class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "island-item"> 
  <img  class = "itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 3">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 3</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
    $60
    <img id = "Hawaiian Shirt 3" onclick = "addToCart()" class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
   </div>
</div>
```

It's not really needed but here is the javaScript code:

```
function addToCart()
{

}
```

As you can see the plus signs have the same onclick but have different ID's. How would I go knowing which plus sign is clicked? Once I get which item is chosen the other information for the shopping cart will be based on the item. If more information is needed I will provide it. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `getAttribute`

```js
const addToCart = ({
  target
}) => {
  console.log(target.getAttribute('id'))
}
document.querySelectorAll('.addCartImg').forEach(add => add.addEventListener('click', addToCart))
```

```html
<div class="island-item">
  <img class="itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 1</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
    $60
    <img id="Hawaiian Shirt 1" class="addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="island-item">
  <img class="itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 2">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 2</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
    $60
    <img id="Hawaiian Shirt 2" class="addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="island-item">
  <img class="itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 3">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 3</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
    $60
    <img id="Hawaiian Shirt 3" class="addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the id of the element to the addToCart function when defining it in the HTML.

```
<div class = "island-item"> 
  <img  class = "itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 1">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 1</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
   $60
   <img id = "Hawaiian Shirt 1" onclick ="addToCart('hawaii_shirt_1')" class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "island-item"> 
 <img  class = "itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 2">
 <center>Hawaiian Shirt 2</center>
 <div class="priceAmount">
   $60
   <img id = "Hawaiian Shirt 2" onclick = "addToCart('hawaii_shirt_2')" class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
  </div>
</div>

<div class = "island-item"> 
  <img  class = "itemImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/IslandTimeHolderShirt.png" alt="Hawaiian Shirt 3">
  <center>Hawaiian Shirt 3</center>
  <div class="priceAmount">
    $60
    <img id = "Hawaiian Shirt 3" onclick = "addToCart('hawaii_shirt_3')" class = "addCartImg" src="assestsForProductsPage/plusSignForCart.jpeg" alt="addCart">
   </div>
</div>
```

and the function

```
function addToCart(id) {
    //do stuff with the id
}
```

edit: fixed quotation marks in HTML

Answer (score 0):

Pass a unique String to Add to cart Function i have removed image and added a button on where the user will click to ad product to cart
Tip: use different quotes for fuction name and parameter value

check codepen below
https://codepen.io/thisiskamaljoshi/pen/KKrmgGL?editors=1111

```
    <div class = "island-item"> 
 <p>Hawaiian Shirt 1</p>
  
 <div class="priceAmount">
   $60

  </div>
  
  <button onclick="addToCart('hawaianshirt1')">Add to cart</button>
</div>

<div class = "island-item"> 
  
  <p>Hawaiian Shirt 2</p>
  <div class="priceAmount">
    $60

   </div>
  <button onclick="addToCart('hawaianshirt2')">Add to cart</button>
</div>
<script>
    function addToCart(value){
      console.log(value)
    }
</script>
```